# phpmyadmin creates incorrect dump

Tags: phpmyadmin

afer having created a dump with phpmyadmin of my database, I noticed, phpmyadmin was setting **actually all** FK constraints like this:

```
  ADD CONSTRAINT `bewerbung_vorschlag_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_bewerber`) REFERENCES `bewerber` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
```

Several constraints are like this

```
  ADD CONSTRAINT `bewerbung_vorschlag_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_bewerber`) REFERENCES `bewerber` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
```

How to set export-options in phpmyadmin creating dump correctly?

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: Versionsinformationen: 4.6.5.2

Comment: Did you try the current stable version? (4.7.4)

Comment: Yes,I did,combined with XAMPP, both are up to date!